BigQuery - Can I setup Alerts for specific Scheduled Queries which begin with a letter rather than applying them to all queries indiscriminately?
I have currently setup Alerting under Log Explorer to email me anytime a scheduled query fails under a particular project. Is there a way I can set these alerts only for a set of scheduled queries that follows a particular naming convention? The reason being, we only need alerts for queries for our team, and we may have more scheduled queries added in the future, so we want to make it future-proof.
Any advice on this would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!
One alternative could be to add config id of each scheduled query, however, that is not the optimal way to configure an alert considering we may have future additions/subtractions.
